# Is necessary to use a submit input in AJAX based forms?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm wondering if it is necessary to use a sumbit input in my AJAX based forms whereas:

1-)These forms must work with AJAX, if a user hasn't javascript he can't use my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not needed, you can use the .submit() function to grab a form submit and make it return false so it doesn't redirect on submit.

Answer (score 1):

Its always best practice to use .submit as it will return the data you require and return false (as already mentioned). More importantly for usability it will allow the browser to show consistent behaviour, for example if a person uses tabs or hits 'enter' on the keyboard to submit.